# Unique pointer to stream

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, move-semantics, unique-ptr

```
#include <memory>
#include <istream>

typedef std::unique_ptr<std::istream> myType;

class myClass{

    myType myStream;
public:

    myClass(myType a_stream){
        myStream = std::move(a_stream); //compiler error
    }

};
```

Why I'm not allowed to move a newly created stream? As far as I know, streams are not copyable, but are movable. Do I miss something? Unique pointer fits especially well for non-copyable objects, at least theorically.

compiler error

```
 no match for 'operator='
```

Comment: What is your compiler? Also, have you `#include`d all the necessary header files?

Comment: GCC 4.8.x and yes of course istream and memory are included. I edit the post

Comment: Well, [I cannot reproduce that](http://ideone.com/QX4PKk)...

Comment: The error that was just posted but has now disappeared said that you were trying to assign from an `istream` to an `ostream` (or the other way round).

Comment: ! gosh 1 what a moron am I! I inverted typedefs! thanks!that worked

Comment: with that fixed it become a duplicate: /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to the constructor is *by-value* -- you have to make it *by-reference*. With *by-value* the object needs to be **copied** when you use the constructor. Ok, you use `unique_ptr`, but it is still copied where it only can be moved.

So, try it like this:

```
myClass(myType &a_stream){
    myStream = std::move(a_stream); //compiler error
}
```

or maybe even

```
myClass(myType &&a_stream){
    myStream = std::move(a_stream); //compiler error
}
```

this is *by-reference* then and no copy at the place where using will occur.

Although, I find it strange that you get the error at the place of `move`, so I may be wrong.

Comment: yeah basically the error was a typo, but you know that GCC output is hard to understand when you get errors ^^. Anyway your answer is good. Actually I'm using move constructors all the way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles for me.  I see nothing wrong with it.